# Understanding Node.js code for emit function esp

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am struggling to get the complete hold of the code below. I want to understand the working of `emit`.

Here is my understanding of the instances of all emits mentioned in the code below.

1. `profileEmitter.emit("error", new Error("There was an error getting the profile for " + username + ". (" + http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode] + ")"));`

It executes the error function.( But I am not sure where error function is defined in the code.

2. `response.on('data', function (chunk) {
           body += chunk;
           profileEmitter.emit("data", chunk);
       });`

This emits a data event function as defined above.All fine ! But what is second parameter. As per the docs this argument should be a listener , but all it is a parameter -  of "anonymous function" defined ahead of data.

3. `try {
                   //Parse the data
                   var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                   profileEmitter.emit("end", profile);
               } catch (error) {
                   profileEmitter.emit("error", error);
               }`

The first emit in the try block has a `profile` variable this time. 
The second emit in the catch block has a `error` as second arg. Well ! All confused.

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var http = require("http");
var util = require("util");


function Profile(username) {

EventEmitter.call(this);

profileEmitter = this;

//Connect to the API URL (http://teamtreehouse.com/username.json)
var request = http.get("http://example.com/" + username + ".json", function(response) {
    var body = "";

    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        request.abort();
        //Status Code Error
        profileEmitter.emit("error", new Error("There was an error getting the profile for " + username + ". (" + http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode] + ")"));
    }

    //Read the data
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
        profileEmitter.emit("data", chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        if(response.statusCode === 200) {
            try {
                //Parse the data
                var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                profileEmitter.emit("end", profile);
            } catch (error) {
                profileEmitter.emit("error", error);
            }
        }
    }).on("error", function(error){
        profileEmitter.emit("error", error);
    });
});
}

util.inherits( Profile, EventEmitter );

module.exports = Profile;
```

Comment: `response.on('data', …)` does not *emit* a "data listener function". Not sure what you meant by that.

Comment: Oops  ! It should be data event followed by listener function.  I will correct the question.Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EventEmitter.emit()` function says just what it says: it sends an event to the listeners that are registered for said event.

The arguments after the first one (the event type) are just arguments of the event, they're not listeners.

So your first call just send an `error` event, with an attached `Error` argument that describes the error.

The second call sends a `data` event, along with the chunk of data that was just received.

The third call sends an `end` event, along with the decoded profile.

The last call sends an `error` event, along with the error received from `catch`.

Comment: Okay, helps ! But is emit function a necessity to execute the function code in node.js ?

Comment: One more question.  You said that the second parameter can be data too. But as per docs, they mention that event will be followed by listeners and according to me listeners are functions only. Please correct me if wrong !

Comment: I think you're incorrectly interpreting the documentation. https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2 says that `emit` "Calls each of the listeners in order with the supplied arguments". The listeners are not provided to emit, they are registered using `on` or `once`. `emit` will call all the listeners that have been registered for that event, and pass the arguments supplied to the listener. The code you quoted does not show the listener part.

Comment: Alright ! This is exactly my concern that the code here doesn't provides the listener as specified in the docs. Instead it just passes on the `chunk` parameter of the anonymous callback in the `on` method. So my confusion was simply because docs say `listener` and not `listener/data`. But I am clear by your explanation that it is okay to pass the data as well ! Hope i got it right this time !

Comment: Well, the goal of this code is to define a new object you can listen on. It's basically starting an HTTP request, listening on it, and then passing data (and errors) along to the listeners you set on it. So somewhere else in your code, you'll create this object, and add listeners to monitor for the `end` event which returns the decode profile received, and possibly the `error` and `data` events.

Comment: @MegaRacer, if the answer helped you, feel free to up vote and/or accept it.

Comment: Not cent % clear but I feel I will get the mechanics as I get along . Sorry for the delayed response. Was just caught up in other stuff. Answer accepted with a +1

Comment: You mentioned in one of the comments above that this code doesn't have a listener. But What is then "end" , "data" and "error" passed as first argument called to the ON method ? Second, can you please provide an example of a code which uses listeners ? Thanks!

Comment: 'end', 'data' and 'error' are the types of the events this object will emit. A listener on this object would simply be `var user = Profile("username"); user.on('end',function(profile) { console.log('received profile:",profile); });`

Answer (score 0):

the all concept of EventEmitter is same as `Observer pattern` in java (if you comes from java world), you observe the event you interested in your example `data` event, and everytime you emit a `data` event by `emit('data', {data})`, it will be handled by the event handler which subscribe the event by `on('data', handlerfunction)`.

`error` is a special event in nodejs, if you don't handle it, it will just blow up your process.